# create an object array with an iteration while

Tags: javascript

I would like to insert each new iteration of value of an array in the form of an object. What am I missing?

```js
x = []
var min=0
var interval = 50
var max = 500

  while(min  < max) {
    min = min+interval,
    x = {

      start: min,
      end: min+interval,
      duration : interval
  
    }
    
    console.log(x)
  }
```

```html
x = []
var min=0
var interval = 50
var max = 500

  while(min  < max) {
    min = min+interval,
    x = {

      start: min,
      end: min+interval,
      duration : interval
  
    }
    
    console.log(x)
  }
```

Expected result :

```
[
 { min: 0,
   max: 50,
   duration: 50
}
 { min: 50,
   max: 100,
   duration: 50
}

]
 ect..
```

Comment: You're not pushing values into array. x.push(tempObj) and log it after loop you will see the correct output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, assigning to the array variable (`x = ...`) does not push to the array like it does in a couple of other languages. It *replaces* the value of the variable (`x`) with what's on the right-hand side.

To push to the array, use its `push` method:

```
x.push({/*...*/});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `x = newObject`  change the value of x to a new object.
to increment your array, you need to use `x.push(objectToPush)`.

```
  x.push({

  start: min,
  end: min+interval,
  duration : interval

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use for instead of while

```
let x = []
var min=0
var interval = 50
var max = 500

  for(let i = 0 ;min  < max; i++) {
    min = min+interval,
    x[i] = {

      start: min,
      end: min+interval,
      duration : interval

    } 
  }
console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array with the wanted length and map objects.

```js
function getItems(min, max, duration) {
    return Array.from({ length: (max - min) / duration }, _ => ({
      min,
      max: min += duration,
      duration
    }));
}

console.log(getItems(50, 500, 50));
```